# How to prove that the modal number(s) of outgoing edges cannot exceed 2?

Tags: graph-theory

This seemingly simple problem is doing my head in. I have tried doing a proof by induction over the edges of the graph but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

I am trying to prove that in a finite directed graph $G = (V, E)$ that obeys the following rules, any mode number of outgoing edges cannot exceed 2.

The rules:

- The graph has $|V| = n$ vertices - I've called them $0, 1, ..., n-2, n-1$.
- The graph has $|E| ≤ n$.
- Every vertex has 0 or 1 incoming edges.
- No vertex has an edge from itself to itself.
- The graphs are constructed by a process of adding edges between pairs of vertices according to the following rules:

  - An edge can be added from any vertex $u$, but only to $v ≠ u$ when $v$ has no incoming edges already.
  - Adding an edge from $u$ to $v$ when $u$ has no incoming edges means an edge must also be added from $v$ to $u$

An example of a graph that follows the rules, with $n = 2$:

- $V = \{0, 1\}$
- $E = \{ (0, 1), (1, 0) \}$
- Mode = 1

  - there are 2 vertices with 1 outgoing edge
  - therefore the modal number of outgoing edges is 1.

Another example of a graph that follows the rules, with $n = 4$:

- $V = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$
- $E = \{ (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 2), (1, 3) \}$
- Set of all modes = $\{0, 2\}$ (multimodal - see below)

  - there are 2 vertices with 0 outgoing edges
  - there are 2 vertices with 2 outgoing edges
  - therefore there are two modal numbers of outgoing edges: 0, and 2.

The way I tried to formulate the inductive step was to let $T_r$ denote the set of nodes that have $r$ outbound edges, and then to say:

For some $i$ in $\{0, 1, 2\}$, for all $j$ in $\{3, 4, ..., n-2, n-1\}$, $|T_i| > |T_j|$.

But I tie myself in knots trying to cover all the cases in making the inductive step.

Any help appreciated.

I feel like I'm going down a blind alley on this one. I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample either...

Comment: What is a modal number of an edge?  And is it of an edge, or, as you have it in the title, of a vertex?

Comment: @LSpice I think, it is a standard statistical terminology applied to the multiset of $n$ outdegrees of the graph.

Comment: @LSpice Hi I have corrected the title and also fixed the "rules" of the graph.

Comment: @FedorPetrov that is what I mean here yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of outdegrees is at most $n$. Thus if certain value $d\geqslant 3$ appears, say, $k>0$ times, the value 0 must appear at least $(d-1)k>k$ times, and do $d$ is not modal.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why the value 0 must appear at least $(d-1)k$ times? I guess this refers to the vertices at the ends of the $d$ outgoing edges, but they could have non-zero outdegrees of their own, couldn't they? I don't see the connection between the sum of outdegrees being $n$ and your following statements.

Comment: If 0 appears at most $(d-1)k-1$ times, then the total sum is at least $dk+n-dk+1>n$

Comment: After we observed that the sum of outdegrees is at most $n$, we may forget about the graph at all

Comment: Thanks Fedor, I need to look at this in more detail as I am not understanding it just by reading it through. Any more detailed step-by-step instructions are welcome. However in the meantime I will try to understand it and come back with more specific questions. Thanks

Comment: You have $n$ non-negative integers with sum at most $n$. There are $k$ integers equal to $d$. Thus the sum of rest $n-k$ integers is at most $n-kd$. Therefore at most $n-kd$ of them are positive, and others (at least $k(d-1)$ integers) are equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks – I understand the first three sentences. However the last one – I don't understand how you arrive there or what it means. You say "$n-kd$ of them are positive" – I know $n-kd$ is the sum of the $n - k$ integers, but I don't see how it refers to a number of elements of the set. When you say "$n-kd$ of them are positive", what is the "them"? I don't understand the second half of the last sentence either but maybe I will get there when I understand the first half.

Comment: them are these $n$ integers (outdegrees of your graph)

Comment: Thanks I managed to understand this by working through the algebra with your terminology and another variable $s ≤ n$ where $s$ is the sum of the outdegrees. I found that the number of zeroes $z$ must be $≥ 2k$ as you did in your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133757/discussion-between-r-u-c-k-s-a-c-k-and-fedor-petrov).